# Multiple subscriptions on the GPS device

Tags: android, gps

I'm programming a Android application which have a background service that polls the GPS now and then. My question regards if it's possible for other applications to access the GPS during my service uses it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your App will not prevent other Apps from receiving position updates. Android will start the GPS receiver when it needs to serve calls to listener registered with `requestLocationUpdates()`. This works for multiple Apps at the same time.

The only interferece will be that when Android is already serving updates, there is no warm-up phase when you register a new listener.